# Keycloak: user getting its info (id, groups, etc...)

Tags: api, keycloak, keycloak-services

I need a suggestion on how to perform this. I'm using the Keycloak API to perform requests like retrieve users, groups, or other CRUD operations. All these ops can be done with the admin account; what if I would a user, using its own access token, to access only to its own information? Is there a specific endpoint I haven't seen in the documentation or is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By postman:

{{yourKeycloakServer}}/auth/realms/{{yourRealm}}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo

with accesstoken and POST method.

Comment: Please add some more details about your answer.

Comment: I don't think this does the trick; I need a user A, that is not ad admin, to be authenticated and to make a call to get its own groups. From the "userinfo" endpoint I can only get openid profile email phone, as told here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo . Maybe, whether there's the possibility to define a new claim taking the groups of the user...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any specific endpoint to see only user's own metadata, but it is possible to create a new user in Master realm and restrict it's access to Admin API. 
For example, we can grant to that user only certain roles like View/Manage Users of only one specific Realm. This way we don't need to use server's primary admin account.

Comment: But, what if, using only one realm (let's say the master one) I need a user A to use his access token to get his groups, even if it's not an admin? Is it possible to create a client that allows a user to access to the groups?

Comment: Maybe there is a better way, but what prevents you from creating your own operation for this purpose, using the Admin API and one of the master's realm user and expose it to your user A?